# Автопрокрутка списка изображений ListView.builder до последнего flutter

Tags: flutter

Всем здравствуйте. У меня есть список PageListView. Он получает из api данные и на их основе формирует список карточек. Внутри карточки есть ListView.builder (он формирует что-то вроде слайдера из изображений. Пока карточка находится на экране - всё работает нормально. Но стоит сделать скролл, а потом вернуться к тому же месту и изображения в карточке автопрокручиваются в конец. Нужно, чтобы они сохраняли своё положение.
Пример кода моей карточки

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ocoche/res/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:ocoche/views/user/sign/sign_in.dart';
import 'package:ocoche/widgets/vehicle/ads_form/title_form.dart';

Widget adsCard(
    var function, String title, String price, List photos, String description,String address,var favoriteFunction,bool isVin, bool isTop, bool isFavorite,String day,var signFunction,var key) {
//int countOfPage;
     if( photos.length!=0){
      int indexOfMove;
    for(int i = 0; i <photos.length; i++){
      if(photos[i].main==true){
        indexOfMove = i;
      }
    }
    print('indexOfMove - $indexOfMove');
    var temp = photos[0];
    photos[0]=photos[indexOfMove];
    photos[indexOfMove]= temp;
   //  countOfPage  = photos.length~/16;
     }
   
  return InkWell(
   //key:UniqueKey(),
    onTap: function,
    child: Container(
     
      decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)), color:AppColors.white,),
        width: 343.0,
        height: 377.0,
        margin:EdgeInsets.only(left:16.0,right:16.0,bottom:16.0),
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                titleForm(title, EdgeInsets.zero, 17.0, FontWeight.w500,
                    letterSpacing: -0.08,
                    color: AppColors.indigo700,
                    lineHeight: 24.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft),
                    InkWell(
                              child: isFavorite
                        ? Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:2.5,right:2.5,top:1.5,bottom:1.0),
                          child: Image.asset(
                              'assets/iconsNew/icon-bookmark.png',
                              width: 20.0,
                              height: 20.0,
                              color: AppColors.yellow700,
                            ),
                        )
                        : Image.asset(
                            'assets/iconsNew/bookmark-appBar.png',
                            width: 24.0,
                            height: 24.0,
                            color: AppColors.indigo400,
                          ),
                              onTap: isAuthorization ?favoriteFunction : signFunction,
                            )
                        ,
              ],
            ),
            titleForm('€ ' + price.toString(),
                EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, bottom: 14.0), 21.0, FontWeight.w900,
                lineHeight: 20.0,
                letterSpacing: -0.08,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                color: AppColors.indigo700),
                Container(
                    height: 184.0,
                  child:
                  photos.length==0
                  ?Image.asset('images/default_auto.png', fit:BoxFit.cover,width:295.0,height:184.0)
                   :
                   ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: photos.length,
                    scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return Container(
                      margin:EdgeInsets.only(right:2.0),
                      child: Image.network(photos[index].url, fit:BoxFit.cover,width:295.0,height:184.0));}
                   
                    ),
                ),
            // CarouselSlider.builder(
            //     //carouselController: carouselController,
            //     itemCount: photos.length,
            //     itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index, int i) {
            //       return Container(
            //         margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:2.0),
            //         decoration: BoxDecoration(
            //           image: DecorationImage(
            //             image: NetworkImage(photos[index].url),
            //             fit: BoxFit.cover,
            //           ),
            //         ),
            //       );
            //     },
            //     options: CarouselOptions(
            //         height: 184.0,
            //         viewportFraction: 1,
            //         enableInfiniteScroll: false,
            //         enlargeCenterPage: false,
            //         reverse: false,
            //         initialPage: 0,
            //         scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            //         onPageChanged: (index, reason) {})),
            titleForm(description, EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0, bottom: 10.0),
                15.0, FontWeight.normal,
                lineHeight: 16.0,
                letterSpacing: 0.07,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                color: AppColors.indigo700),
            Row(
              children: [
              isVin  ?Image.asset('assets/iconsNew/icon-top.png',
                    width: 36.0, height: 16.0):SizedBox(height:16.0),
                SizedBox(width: 4.0),
              isTop ?  Image.asset('assets/iconsNew/icon-vin.png',
                    width: 36.0, height: 16.0) :SizedBox(height: 16.0,)
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              margin:EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0,bottom:10.0),
              child: Divider(color: AppColors.indigo100,height:1.0)),
              Row(
                children: [
                  titleForm(address, EdgeInsets.zero, 13.0, FontWeight.normal,lineHeight: 16.0,letterSpacing: 0.07,color:AppColors.indigo500,alignment:Alignment.centerLeft),
                  titleForm('•', EdgeInsets.only(left:4.0,right:4.0), 13.0, FontWeight.normal,lineHeight: 16.0,letterSpacing: 0.07,color:AppColors.indigo500,alignment:Alignment.centerLeft),
                  titleForm(day, EdgeInsets.zero, 13.0, FontWeight.normal,lineHeight: 16.0,letterSpacing: 0.07,color:AppColors.indigo500,alignment:Alignment.centerLeft),
                ],
              )
          ],
        )),
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60293181/8387227

Comment: Спасибо)) Неделю маялся этой проблемой

Comment: Добавьте ответ с вашим решением, чтобы помочь другим с этим вопросом.